# Fonts are not properly displayed in X applications

Tags: fonts

Why my `r` is looking like <del>`r`</del>? Just look at the images

[image: letter 'r' in name of folder]

[image: letter 'r' in google chome toolbar]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart. (these are some additional characters to satisfy the 30 char minimum)

Answer (score 2):

A simple restart should do the trick :)